# Store File object from Javascript Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

i have promise function which returns a File object like this
[image]

I want to store File object from promise into array like this

```
photo = [File object,File object]
```

i try with `photo.push(~resultPromises~)` but the photo array still empty

this is my store function

```
let photo = []

file1.then(function (result) {
  photo.push(result)
});
```

Comment: `await file1.then(function...` ?

Comment: wow thanks it work

Comment: then better `let photo = [ await file1 ];`

Comment: That's much better @Thomas =D